# Как прокрутить страницу нажатием "вниз"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно прокрутить страницу вниз на кол-во пикселей, которое будет вычислено функцией `document.documentelement.clientheight`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
var y = $(window).scrollTop();  //твоя текущая позиция
$(window).scrollTop(y+150);
```

***Подробный пример + анимация***:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#scroll').fadeIn(200);
  });
  $('#scroll').click(function() { // When button is clicked
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 150 // Scroll to 150px of the top
    }, 500); 
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>
    <button id="scroll">Scroll to The Point</button>
  </p>
</body>
```

ps. Вопросы будут, могу пример подробный написать.

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать анимированый скролл

Comment: @BedOmar Я обновил свой ответ, добавив пример с анимацией, можете посмотреть, от использования `$(window).scrollTop(y+150)` отказался в данном случае.

Answer (score 2):

`clientHeight` - это не функция, а свойство, ну да ладно.

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.clientHeight);
```